# Loop through table rows append unique number to all input field name attributes

Tags: jquery

I'm not too familiar with jquery, learning on the job I Guess.

I have this table:

```
<table id="Table">

<tr><th>First Col</th><th>Second Col</th><th>Third Col</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="name_7" value="3" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="age_7" value="3" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="town_7" value="3" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input name="name_9" value="4" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="age_9" value="4" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="town_9" value="4" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input name="name_11" value="5" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="age_11" value="5" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="town_11" value="5" type="text"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

on page load I need to loop through each table row and change the appended number on each input name, so the new table will look like this:

```
<table id="Table">

<tr><th>First Col</th><th>Second Col</th><th>Third Col</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="name_1" value="3" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="age_1" value="3" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="town_1" value="3" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input name="name_2" value="4" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="age_2" value="4" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="town_2" value="4" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input name="name_3" value="5" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="age_3" value="5" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="town_3" value="5" type="text"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

just to help as much as I can, I found this code that works well with renaming the name attribute

`this.name = this.name.replace(/\d+/, counter + 1);`

I'm using it in a similar manner but for a different purpose

like always any help will be more than appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cnt = 1;

    $("#Table").find("tr").each(function() {


        $(this).find("input").each(function() {

               this.name = this.name.replace(/\d+/, cnt);

           });

        cnt = cnt + 1;
    });

    });
```

is there any way I can improve on this?

any answers appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the rows and change the names of the cells based on the index in the iteration

```
$('#Table tr:not(:has(th))').each(function(index, row) {
    $(row).find('td input').attr('name', function(i, n) {
        return n.split('_').shift() + '_' + (index + 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, had a bug there, should work now, assuming you want to change the attributes, not the properties, in which case you'd change `attr` to `prop`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` function's index parameter instead of creating a counter variable:

```
$('#Table').find('tr').each(function(ndx, row){
    $(row).find('input').each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).attr('name', name.replace(/\d+/, ndx));
    });
});
```